# How to add _host.cshtml file to Razor pages project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor-server-side

I have followed this tutorial and I am 
[Using Razor Components In A Razor Page](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/338/using-razor-components-in-a-razor-page).
I execute razor components in a razor page using

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<WEKA.Components.Sortiment>(RenderMode.Server))
```

which works OK.

But every package (e.g. [matBlazor](https://www.matblazor.com/)) I am trying to use wants me to modify `_host.cshtml` file. I do not have such a file in my ASP.NET Core 3.0 Razor pages project - it is a file for routing within Blazor app - not sure where to put it in Razor pages project and what it should contain.

Anyone can give me a hint about that?

---

I found out simply by trying (I am new to this and did not study the background) that when I modify `_layout.cshtml` instead of `_host.cshtml` and add an empty `_host.cshtml` file to Pages folder, after that [matBlazor](https://www.matblazor.com/) starts to work OK.